# CMake: Source file depends on source file

Tags: cmake

I am embedding a source file into another source file using inline assembly and .incbin, which is just like I want it. I will not accept the standard objcopy method, which while works is (imho) the lesser method. xxd is also an option, but really only for very small includes. I have a static site builder that takes a lot of resources and packs it into a single program, which is very quick with .incbin.

Unfortunately, adding the JS file to the list of sources is not enough:

```
ninja explain: output CMakeFiles/jsapp.dir/static_site.c.o older than most recent input static_site.c (1629797306094133842 vs 1629797311521966739)
ninja explain: CMakeFiles/jsapp.dir/static_site.c.o is dirty
ninja explain: jsapp is dirty
[2/2] Linking C executable jsapp
```

The main C file that embeds the JS is not being rebuilt, but the static site source which is unrelated here is because the timestamp changed.

How can I tell CMake that source.c now depends on some_file.js?

Comment: "How can I tell CMake that source.c now depends on some_file.js?" - If you want an executable, created from `source.c`, to recompile when `some_file.js` is changed, then just add `some_file.js` to the list of sources: According to the extension `.js` CMake will understand that given file shouldn't be compiled, but appropriate dependency will be added.

Comment: Adding the JS file to sources did not help, because the JS file is quite literally included as a binary segment in the source.o object. I need to tell CMake that when some_file.js changes, then so does source.c.

Comment: Maybe setting this property will help? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html#prop_sf:OBJECT_DEPENDS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @arrowd 's idea:

```
set_source_files_properties(main.c OBJECT_DEPENDS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my.js
)
```

Worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm recently doing exactly the same work, and I'm redirected to this question from my own duplicate question.

According to [CMake official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html), the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` property only works on *makefile* and *ninja* generators, but would take no effect on IDE generators like *Visual Studio* and *XCode*. So I tried another way to do it. In brief:

- The pure-inline-assembly part is generated to a separate source file (let's say `rcs_asm.cpp`). Other auxiliary code parts (exists in my situation) is generated to another C++ file (let's say `rcs_blob.cpp`).
- The `rcs_asm.cpp` is manually compiled to object file (let's say `rcs_asm.o`) with `cmake_custom_command` which allows you to specify file-level dependency:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rcs_asm.o
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rcs_asm.cpp
    DEPENDS ${all_those_input_resource_files}
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" -c -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rcs_asm.o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rcs_asm.cpp
    VERBATIM)
```

- the generated object file and blob C++ file is then compiled into a library:

```
add_library(rcs_lib STATIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rcs_blob.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rcs_asm.o)
```

The separation of pure-inline-assembly part make `rcs_asm.cpp` needs no optimization flags, so you don't need to compile in different build types with their flags accordingly, thus don't need to work with nasty generator expressions.